# Facebook API's method: isSessionValid() always returns true

Tags: android, facebook

I am using the [official facebook SDK for Android](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/) and I am facing some issues regarding session management. Specifically, I don't know how to test whether the session is still valid or not.

First I initialize and authorize a connexion to facebook:

```
Facebook facebook = new Facebook(context.getString(R.string.facebook_app_id));
facebook.authorize(...); // Works ok
```

Then, I want to disconnect the user:

```
facebook.logout(context);
```

But once I have done that, the following **still** returns *true*:

```
facebook.isSessionValid();
```

Why does it return *true*?

Anything I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Where are you calling `isSessionValid`? May be you are calling it immediately after calling `logout`, when the logout process is not complete. wait for `fbDidLogout` to be called on the `FBSessionDelegate`. Before that callback, the session can be still valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you encountered an older bug. Is your Facebook SDK up to date?

According to [the source](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/facebook/src/com/facebook/android/Facebook.java), logout calls `setAccessToken(null);`. And if the token is null, `isSessionValid()` should return false. Here is it's code for reference:

```
public boolean isSessionValid() {
    return (getAccessToken() != null) &&
            ((getAccessExpires() == 0) ||
                    (System.currentTimeMillis() < getAccessExpires()));
}
```

The getter/setter doesn't do any null-checks either, so the call in logout() should have the desired effect.

Answer (score 2):

Im not sure how you integrated facebook in your app but are you checking the access token from the shared preferences? If you are I would check to see that you are actually setting the new access token.  For example, after the log out you would want to write out that new access token (null) so next time it would prompt the user to log in again.