# isSessionValid() returns true, and it really isn't

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-android-sdk

Hey weird problem over here.

I'm checking if a user as a valid access_token and if not i authorize.
Now i'm using this code :

```
      mPrefs = getSharedPreferences("Facebook", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String access_token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
        long expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);
        if(access_token != null) {
            facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);
        }
        if(expires != 0) {
            facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
        }

        if(!facebook.isSessionValid()) {
            // preform authorize dialog

            }
            else
            {
             //break into pentagon
            }
```

and `isSessionValid()` is returning that it is valid.
and right after that i make a request to Open Graph, which returning :

```
    {"error":{
"type":"OAuthException",
"message":"Error validating access token: Session has expired at unix time 1337364000.
 The current unix time is 1337802012.",
"error_subcode":463,
"code":190}}
```

And that leaves me very confused.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8647062/1026199) answer suggested the asker that he uses an outdated SDK source, which is **not** the problem in my case.

So i checked the source code of the Facbook SDK and this is the method :

```
  public boolean isSessionValid() {
    return (getAccessToken() != null) &&
            ((getAccessExpires() == 0) ||
                    (System.currentTimeMillis() < getAccessExpires()));
}
```

Which made me think it has something to do with the fact i'm running the App on the emulator because it has different time then the actuall time, but that dosen't make sense to me, maybe i'm wrong, and if i'm wrong and this is the problem how can i solve it?

And if it's not, Does anyone know what may cause this issue?

Comment: Since the Facebook SDK is a library project, you can debug it and see why `isSessionValid()` is returning true. Check what `System.currentTimeMillis()` and `getAccessExpires()` return and compare them to the values in the Facebook error. There is also a new method to [extend your access token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/#extend_token) that Facebook says you should use in `onResume()`.

Comment: I am extending the token, and getAccessExpires gets the long of the token.